# UIView animation with multiple animation

Tags: xcode, uiview

I wrote this a series of code that move the `UIIMAGE` from CENTER to LEFT position then will appear two textfields afterward too. The animation worked fine however that `UIIMAGE` will move back to the original (CENTER) location after I tapped on either one textfield. Please advise.

Here my code:

```
-(void)moveLogoLeft{
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationDelay:0.0];
img_CPLLogo.frame = CGRectMake(130.0f, 230.0f, img_Logo.frame.size.width, img_Logo.frame.size.height);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

}

and making a `UIButton' to trigger the action

```
-(IBAction)doShowTextfield:(id)sender{
[UIView animateWithDuration:0 animations:^{
[btm_welcome setAlpha:0];
img_Logo.frame = CGRectMake(100.0f, 230.0f, img_Logo.frame.size.width, img_Logo.frame.size.height);

}completion:^(BOOL completed){
    [self showTextfield];
}];
}
}
```

What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `UITextField`'s `delegate` method for your requirement:

```
 - (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
 {
   [UIView animateWithDuration:0 animations:^{
   [
      //do your requirement here
   }completion:^(BOOL completed){
      //do anything more here
   }];
   }
 }
```

Comment: I found that if I used the plug-in "MBProgress", the logo will also center it when the textfield is on focus too...so I must center the img_logo whenever the textfield is on focus?

Comment: I meant if a user TAP on a textfield, apology this is another programming language.  The above, I don't want the img_logo to be in the center of the screen.

Comment: that what i meant when tapped - (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing willl be called

Comment: thanks for the comment, this is my workflow: (1) a logo will show in the center (2) tap [UIButton] to call instance making logo move to the left, textfield will show on the right (3) tap textfield start editing (the logo didn't move yet), but after I clicked [OK], another instance will be called (with MBProgress `[self.view addSubview:HUD];`), the logo will be moved to center, but once the MBProgress is removed, the logo won't be moved.

Comment: so it is okay to use your code in this case too? Please accept my ignorant